# Initialize a controller with my root controller using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I get an issue when requiring my root controller using NodeJS.

All my controllers are in the same folder.

**My root controller (0-RootController.js):**

```
var RootController = Object.create(null);
RootController.rootUrl = '/';
module.exports = RootController;
```

**My user controller (UserController.js) :**

```
var RootController = require('0-RootController');
var UserController = Object.create(RootController);
UserController.baseUrl = '/user';
module.exports = UserController;
```

**Issue :**

```
Error: Cannot find module '0-RootController'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\app\controllers\UserController.js:9:2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require('0-RootController')` could be used if there were `0-RootController` NPM package.

In case it's relative path, it should be:

```
var RootController = require('./0-RootController');
```